# Trouble initializing and incrementing a static member variable

Tags: c++, variables, static

I am new to C++ and I'm facing trouble with my code here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
  public:
    string student_name;
    double CGPA;
    string degree;
    static unsigned int count_total_no_of_students_enrolled; //STATIC VARIABLE
    const string uni_name = "umt";
    
    void setstudent(string a, double b, string c);
    void displaystudent();
    void display_total_no_of_student();

};

void Student::setstudent(string a, double b, string c) {
   student_name = a;
   CGPA = b;
   degree = c;

   count_total_no_of_students_enrolled++; //******THIS ISN'T WORKING******
}

void Student::displaystudent() {
   cout << "\n=> Student details:\n";
   cout << "   Name: "<< student_name << ",CGPA: " << CGPA << "\n   Degree: " << degree << ",University: " << uni_name;
}

void Student::display_total_no_of_student() {
   cout << "\n Total Students Enrolled: " << count_total_no_of_students_enrolled;
 }

int main() {

   Student s1, s2, s3;

   s1.setstudent("John Doe", 3.5 , "CS");
   s2.setstudent("Jane Doe", 3.9 , "CS");
   s3.setstudent("Jim Doe", 3.8, "CA");

   s1.displaystudent(); s2.displaystudent(); s3.displaystudent();
 
  display_total_no_of_student(); //*****THIS GIVES ERROR TOO*****

  return 0;
}
```

Everything works as expected except for the `static` variable. I want to increment its value by 1 each time a new object of the `Student` class is created. Any help you provide would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two errors in your code are:

1. Your call to `display_total_no_of_student()` doesn't provide either a class object or a class name for that function, so the compiler is looking for a 'free' function of that name/signature, which it doesn't find.
2. Although you have provided a *declaration* for the static `count_total_no_of_students_enrolled` member, you haven't given an actual definition for it (which must be done outside the class definition).

For the first issue, you would most likely want to declare `display_total_no_of_student` as a `static` function (because it doesn't use or require any *specific instance* of the `Student` class). For the second issue, just provide a definition of the `count_total_no_of_students_enrolled` member, which should be initialized to zero.

Here is a 'working' version of your code, with these issues addressed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    string student_name;
    double CGPA;
    string degree;
    static unsigned int count_total_no_of_students_enrolled; // This DECLARES the variable but doesn't define it!
    const string uni_name = "umt";

    void setstudent(string a, double b, string c);
    void displaystudent();
    static void display_total_no_of_student(); // Declare this function as static!
};

unsigned int Student::count_total_no_of_students_enrolled = 0; // This is the REQUIRED definition and initial value!

void Student::setstudent(string a, double b, string c)
{
    student_name = a;
    CGPA = b;
    degree = c;

    count_total_no_of_students_enrolled++; //******THIS ISN'T WORKING******
}

void Student::displaystudent()
{
    cout << "\n=> Student details:\n";
    cout << "   Name: " << student_name << ",CGPA: " << CGPA << "\n   Degree: " << degree << ",University: " << uni_name;
}

void Student::display_total_no_of_student()
{
    cout << "\n Total Students Enrolled: " << count_total_no_of_students_enrolled;
}

int main()
{
    Student s1, s2, s3;

    s1.setstudent("John Doe", 3.5, "CS");
    s2.setstudent("Jane Doe", 3.9, "CS");
    s3.setstudent("Jim Doe", 3.8, "CA");

    s1.displaystudent(); s2.displaystudent(); s3.displaystudent();

    Student::display_total_no_of_student(); // Specify the class name to access a static member function!

    return 0;
}
```

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Dang! Thanks man. You made it crystal clear for me to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Static variables need to be initialized. Initialize the static variable outside the declaration.

The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified void. The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the static data member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator. The initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class (3.3.7).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Adrian's answer regarding `static`:

You only declare the `static` variable `count_total_no_of_students_enrolled` inside the class - you need to provide a corresponding definition. You have two options here: either provide the definition before `main` like so:

```cpp
    unsigned int Student::count_total_no_of_students_enrolled = 0;
```

or consider using C++17's [inline variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

```cpp
    class Student {
    static inline unsigned int count_total_no_of_students_enrolled = 0;
    //...
    }
```

Prior to C++17, the first one was the only option available. This was because, a `class` declaration does not really allocate storage: it's a declaration. However, your `static` variables exist independently of objects of your class and so you had to provide a single definition for them somewhere outside, so that the compiler could allocate storage. C++17's `inline` variables make this a bit more ergonomic.